# Is it possible to use Firebase database with non-ssl Heroku hosted site with a custom domain?

Tags: ssl, heroku, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm planning to host a website for a class in school on Heroku. I've bought a custom domain to be used with it but I would rather not pay the extra cost for having that domain use an SSL certificate through Heroku. I hope to use Firebase database with it for its real-time capabilities and ease of use.

Is it possible to use Firebase with a website hosted on Heroku that is accessed using the non-SSL custom domain?

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Database can only be access through SSL. But a web app accessing the Firebase Database can run on non-secure HTTP.

You might want to consider using [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/) though, since that includes HTTPS hosting for free.